# Vary Plots By Different Date Ranges In RShiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to make a shiny app that plots a custom ggplot `plot1` depending on the different dates. 
The parameter of `plot1` is `days` which plots by different dates as the days are specified accordingly. However, I just can't figure out how to integrate into the server part of shiny. Here is my best approach:

```
# create sample data frame with dates
set.seed(1)
date = seq(Sys.Date(), by = "day", length.out = 30)
number = 100 * rnorm(30)
df = data.frame(date = date, number = number)
head(df)


# Plot
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

plot1 <- function(days) {
  df %>% filter(between(date, max(df$date) - days, max(df$date))) %>%

    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = number)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_classic()
}

# Shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "daterange",
    label = "Select the date range",
    start = min(df$date), 
    end = max(df$date), 
  ),

  plotOutput("plotA") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotA <- renderPlot({
    plot1(input$daterange)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please check your code that you're not missing any packages and that it's reproducible.

Comment: the problem is that `input$daterange` results in two dates (start and end) whereas `plot1` only takes one argument. Use `input$daterange[1]` or `[2]` according to what you want to do

Comment: @ bretauv I already tried `input$daterance[1]` or `[2]` which still doesn't work. The plots won't vary. I think the `filter` part is not correct in terms of what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `filter` a masked function for you?  You can try using a qualified function call to `filter` via `dplyr::filter()`.

Other than that, as the other user pointed out, `input$daterange` is a vector with 2 values - a "beginning" (`input$daterange[1]`) and an "end" (`input$daterange[2]`).  You mentioned that you tried changing `input$daterange[1]` or `[2]`, but it doesn't work: I presume that means you changed your call to `plot(input$daterange)` in `server`, right?  You should be changing and specifying that up in your declaration of that function.  Since you define the date from `input$daterange` based on `min(df$date)` and `max(df$date)` already, you can just use `days[1]` and `days[2]` to refer to the `min` and `max` of the user input.  Maybe like this?

```
plot1 <- function(days) {
  df %>% dplyr::filter(between(date, days[1], days[2])) %>%

    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = number)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_classic()
}
```

Finally, I have had some issues displaying plots from `ggplot` in `shiny` apps myself.  In order to show the plot, I store in a variable, and then explicity show the plot with `print()`.  Example:

```
myPlot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=..., y=...)) + geoms_...
print(myPlot)
```

If I simply call `ggplot` without the `print()` after, it does not always work as intended.